# MySQL ODBC test connection failing

Tags: mysql, odbc, windows-10, driver

I am trying to install and test a MySQL ODBC Connector on my laptop (Windows 10), but, when I configure and test the connection, I keep getting the following error:

Connection Failed
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Access denied for user 'root'@'(localhost)' (using password: YES):

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your connection credentials stored as I'm assuming the password is incorrect yes?

Comment: can you paste your connection configuration please, and let us know what your login credentials are set to at db server level?

Comment: Apologies was away for the weekend. Can you explain what those are and how I would obtain the login details at db server level?

I have two MySQL drivers I am trying to connect to ANSI and Unicode drivers. Configuration details:
TCP/IP Server: localhost 
Port: 3306
User: root
Password:

Comment: when setting up the ODBC drivers you need to make sure your credentials that you are providing in the config match the server login details. Your localhost identifies the installation of MySQL as being on your local machine, which is fine, but you need to know the username and password that you are using to connect with. - So for you I'm assuming all you will need to do is change the ODBC config to include root as the username and password to match whatever you have recorded for the root user in MySQL

Comment: Most of the time if this hasn't been changed it will be blank. obviously not good practice to use root, given its a root account and should be reserved for admin access, you should setup a new user really with some different credentials, as if an account becomes corrupt you can get back in.

Comment: This is the thing. Initially I used the login credentials for when I set up Mysql. It kept coming back with connection failed error messages. 

I'm having the same problem on trying to connect to Microsoft SQL server driver - however I did not need to set up login details on installation.

Comment: I see you are having issues, please follow through the below example of how to implement, there must be something you are missing somewhere: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-dsn-windows-5-2.html